# How do I retrieve the version of a file from a batch file on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, batch-file, version

Binary files have a version embedded in them - easy to display in Windows Explorer.

[image]

How can I retrieve that file version, from a batch file?

Comment: Any hints here?
[http://www.winvistatips.com/determine-version-exe-thru-batch-file-t284289.html](http://www.winvistatips.com/determine-version-exe-thru-batch-file-t284289.html)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version

Answer (score 34, accepted):

and three ways without external tools

1.**WMIC**

```
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="C:\\install.exe" get Version /format:Textvaluelist
```

Pay attention to the double slashes of file name.

Ready to use script:

```
@echo off
:wmicVersion pathToBinary [variableToSaveTo]
setlocal
set "item=%~1"
set "item=%item:\=\\%"


for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name='%item%' get Version /format:Textvaluelist"`) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"
)

if "%~2" neq "" (
    endlocal & (
        echo %version%
        set %~2=%version%
    )
) else (
    echo %version%
)
```

2.[**MAKECAB**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/makecab/fileinf.bat)
as the WMIC is not installed on home versions of windows here's a way with makecab that will run on every windows machine:

```
; @echo off
;;goto :end_help
;;setlocal DsiableDelayedExpansion
;;;
;;;
;;; fileinf /l list of full file paths separated with ;
;;; fileinf /f text file with a list of files to be processed ( one on each line )
;;; fileinf /? prints the help
;;;
;;:end_help

; REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
; set NLM=^


; set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
; if "%~1" equ "/?" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; if "%~2" equ "" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
; if "%~1" equ "/l" (
;  set "_files=%~2"
;  echo !_files:;=%NL%!>"%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  set _process_file="%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  goto :get_info
; )

; if "%~1" equ "/f" if exist "%~2" (
;  set _process_file="%~2"
;  goto :get_info
; )

; echo incorect parameters & exit /b 1
; :get_info
; set "file_info="

; makecab /d InfFileName=%TEMP%\file.inf /d "DiskDirectory1=%TEMP%" /f "%~f0"  /f %_process_file% /v0>nul

; for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%f in ("%TEMP%\file.inf") do (
;  set "file_info=%%f"
;  echo !file_info:,=%nl%!
; )

; endlocal
;endlocal
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.inf 2>nul
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.path 2>nul
; exit /b 0

.set DoNotCopyFiles=on
.set DestinationDir=;
.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFooter=;
.set InfHeader=;
.Set ChecksumWidth=8
.Set InfDiskLineFormat=;
.Set Cabinet=off
.Set Compress=off
.Set GenerateInf=ON
.Set InfDiskHeader=;
.Set InfFileHeader=;
.set InfCabinetHeader=;
.Set InfFileLineFormat=",file:*file*,date:*date*,size:*size*,csum:*csum*,time:*time*,vern:*ver*,vers:*vers*,lang:*lang*"
```

example output (it has a string version which is a small addition to wmic method :) ):

```
c:> fileinfo.bat /l C:\install.exe
    file:install.exe
    date:11/07/07
    size:562688
    csum:380ef239
    time:07:03:18a
    vern:9.0.21022.8
    vers:9.0.21022.8 built by: RTM
    lang:1033
```

**3** Using ***shell.application*** and hybrid batch\jscript.Here's [**tooptipInfo.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat) :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    rem :: the first argument is the script name as it will be used for proper help message
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

////// 
FSOObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;
if (ARGS.Length < 1 ) {
 WScript.Echo("No file passed");
 WScript.Quit(1);
}
var filename=ARGS.Item(0);
var objShell=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
/////


//fso
ExistsItem = function (path) {
    return FSOObj.FolderExists(path)||FSOObj.FileExists(path);
}

getFullPath = function (path) {
    return FSOObj.GetAbsolutePathName(path);
}
//

//paths
getParent = function(path){
    var splitted=path.split("\\");
    var result="";
    for (var s=0;s<splitted.length-1;s++){
        if (s==0) {
            result=splitted[s];
        } else {
            result=result+"\\"+splitted[s];
        }
    }
    return result;
}


getName = function(path){
    var splitted=path.split("\\");
    return splitted[splitted.length-1];
}
//

function main(){
    if (!ExistsItem(filename)) {
        WScript.Echo(filename + " does not exist");
        WScript.Quit(2);
    }
    var fullFilename=getFullPath(filename);
    var namespace=getParent(fullFilename);
    var name=getName(fullFilename);
    var objFolder=objShell.NameSpace(namespace);
    var objItem=objFolder.ParseName(name);
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx
    WScript.Echo(fullFilename + " : ");
    WScript.Echo(objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem,-1));

}

main();
```

used against cmd.exe :

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe :
File description: Windows Command Processor
Company: Microsoft Corporation
File version: 6.3.9600.16384
Date created: ?22-?Aug-?13 ??13:03
Size: 347 KB
```

Comment: wmic works well. I've tried it on win server 2012 and windows 8.

Comment: If anyone's still reading this thread - I'm trying to use the WMIC method in a CMD file, redirecting the WMIC output to a file and then parsing the output using FOR. However this completely fails because the output file is UCS-2 LE BOM (according to Notepad++). If I convert it to ASCII manually it works fine. I also tried parsing the command output directly without using a file, but that fails too, presumably for the same reason. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: @Dave - [check this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266) Tomorrow I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks npocmaka, I need to study that in detail but I don't think my problem is to do with an extra CR. I am using WMIC to get a file version: (WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="blahblah" get Version /format:Textvaluelist) and parsing with 'delims=='. The output from WMIC is 'Version=7.0.0.1' but I get nothing back from the FOR at all. Also, I looked for your update but the latest post on the dostips forum you linked to was 14 Apr 2014 and I couldn't find your name at all. Am I missing something??

Comment: In the WMIC example, it doesn't seem to set %version% anywhere

Comment: @Evvo - It is set in this line `for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"`   . Version=something is part of the processed string.

Answer (score 22):

The file version could be simply read without external tools by PowerShell like this:

```
(Get-Item myFile.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

and if you want to read it from an Batch file use:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command (Get-Item myFile.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

and to save the file version to a variable use:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^(Get-Item "myFile.exe"^).VersionInfo.FileVersion`) DO (SET fileVersion=%%F)
echo File version: %fileVersion%
```

I've taken a realtive path here, you could also define it absolutely, like: `C:\myFile.dll`

More information about the file is shown if you omit `.FileVersion`

Comment: I suppose powershell isn't installed by default on Windows vista

Comment: Great answer, it works like charm.

Comment: Thanks, but note that if there are parenthesis in path, for instance in `C:\Program Files (x86)\something\something.exe`, you should put it inside single quotes, not double quotes, with same example: `(Get-Item 'C:\Program Files (x86)\something\something.exe').VersionInfo.FileVersion` with double quote you'll have an error like `x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [`sigcheck.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) from [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062). This is a command-line utility that shows file version number, timestamp information, and digital signature details.

Comment: Filever will not be supported according to MSDN on newer Windows OS's, so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [solution in PowerShell](http://pshscripts.blogspot.com/2009/05/get-fileversioninfops1.html) using FileVersionInfo.

Answer (score 3):

I think [`filever`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) is what you need. It can get the file version for multiple items at the same time and locate files (e.g. EXE, DLL) that differ in size or version number.

Comment: This is not installed by default.

Comment: That works great for 32 bit but doesn't seem to handle 64 bit files

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try using `WMIC` to get file version of all `*.exe` and `*.dll` inside the directory of Skype as example :

```bat
@echo off
Mode 75,3 & color 9E
Title Get File Version of any Program from file list using WMIC by Hackoo
Set "RootFolder=%ProgramFiles%\Skype"
@for %%a in (%RootFolder%) do set "FolderName=%%~na"
Set "File_Version_List=%~dp0%FolderName%_File_Version_List.txt"
Set "ErrorFile=%~dp0%FolderName%_Error.txt
Set Extensions="*.exe" "*.dll"
If exist "%ErrorFile%" Del "%ErrorFile%"
If exist "%File_Version_List%" Del "%File_Version_List%"
echo(
echo          Please wait a while ... Process to get file version ...
set "BuildLineWith=call :BuildLine "
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD /D "%RootFolder%"
@for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /b /s %Extensions%') do (
    set "Version="
    Call :Get_AppName "%%F" AppName
    Call :Add_backSlash "%%F"
    Call :GetVersion !Application! Version
    Call :Remove_backSlash !Application!
    If defined Version (
        (
            echo !Application!
            echo !AppName! ==^> !Version!
            %BuildLineWith%*
        )>> "%File_Version_List%"
    ) else (
        (
            echo Version is not defined in !Application!
            %BuildLineWith%#
        )>> "%ErrorFile%"
    )
)
If Exist "%ErrorFile%" Start "" "%ErrorFile%"
If Exist "%File_Version_List%" Start "" /MAX "%File_Version_List%" & Exit
::*******************************************************************
:GetVersion <ApplicationPath> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represente the full path of the application
Rem without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represente the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)  
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get version /format:Textvaluelist 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Add_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the simple "\" by a double "\\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\"
Set "NewString=\\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Remove_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the double "\\" by a simple "\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\\"
Set "NewString=\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Get_AppName <FullPath> <AppName>
Rem %1 = FullPath
Rem %2 = AppName
for %%i in (%1) do set "%2=%%~nxi"
exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:BuildLine
set "LineChar=%1"
if "%LineChar%"=="" set "LineChar=_"
for /f "tokens=2 skip=4" %%A in ('mode con: /status') do set "WindowColumns=%%A" & goto :GotColumnCount
:GotColumnCount
set "CharLine="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%A in (1,1,%WindowColumns%) do set "CharLine=!CharLine!!LineChar:~0,1!"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
endlocal
echo %CharLine%
goto :eof
::*******************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this code from [Rob Vanderwoude's site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=filever_nt):

```
@ECHO OFF
IF [%1]==[] GOTO Syntax
IF NOT [%2]==[] GOTO Syntax
ECHO.%1 | FIND "?" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Syntax
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO Syntax
IF NOT "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" GOTO Syntax

SETLOCAL
SET FileVer=
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND /I "FileVersion"') DO SET LineNum=%%A
SET /A LineNum += 1
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND "[%LineNum%]"') DO SET FileVer=%%B
SET FileVer
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF

:Syntax
ECHO.
ECHO FileVer.bat,  Version 1.00 for NT 4 / 2000 / XP
ECHO Display the specified file's version number
ECHO.
ECHO Usage:  FILEVER  progfile
ECHO.
ECHO Where:  "progfile" is the name of a Windows executable, DLL, or system file
ECHO.
ECHO Uses SysInternal's STRINGS.EXE, avalable at http://www.sysinternals.com
ECHO.
ECHO Written by Rob van der Woude
ECHO http://www.robvanderwoude.com
```

Looks interesting as it uses STRINGS from SysInternals.