# Get the file version of a dll or exe

Tags: windows, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Command line tool to dump Windows DLL version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version)
>   [How do I retrieve the version of a file from a batch file on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706892/how-do-i-retrieve-the-version-of-a-file-from-a-batch-file-on-windows-vista)

Is it possible to get the file version of a dll or exe file using batch commands  and store it in a variable?

Comment: I can't figure out how to capture the version number in a variable in the batch file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example using sigcheck:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%i IN ('p:\supporttools\sigcheck.exe p:\supporttools\procmon.exe') DO ( IF "%%i %%j"=="File version:" SET filever=%%k )

ECHO The version of the file is %filever%

PAUSE
```

Comment: Better to use sigcheck then filever.  You can easily bundle either little utility with your project to ensure it's available, and both run on XP and up, but filever has a .net dependency.  Also, the -n switch in sigcheck is very helpful, I'm not sure if filever has an equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the Sysinternals utility [SigCheck](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx). 
Try this in your batch script:

```
sigcheck.exe -n YourFile.exe
```

Comment: Thanks.  Both SigCheck and Filever dump the file version.  I am trying to set a variable in the batch file to the file version.  I can't figure that part out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746475/dos-windows-batch-help-in-setting-a-variable-from-command-output

Comment: @Calumet What have you tried so far?