# Programmatically reading the "Details" tab of an executable

Tags: file

I wish to read the values contained within the details tab of a .exe file. At a minimum the 'Title' value under 'Description'. Can anybody advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access this information from a batch-file, consider using [sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) from SysInternals, for example:

```
> sigcheck.exe accesschk.exe
    Verified:       Signed
    Signing date:   21:15 18-1-2015
    Publisher:      Microsoft Corporation
    Description:    Reports effective permissions for securable objects
    Product:        Sysinternals AccessChk
    Prod version:   5.21
    File version:   5.21
    MachineType:    32-bit
```

For more tips read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/602802/932282) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700087/932282) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable.
Assuming that you wanna look at the windows files.

If you wanna look at linux files (which are not .exe) - you probably need this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format