# Batch file: How to find the newest version of a file in a directory that has many subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Details:

I want to search in directory 'A', for a file: 'file.jar'
However, directory A does not have any files directly. Instead, it is composed of over 100 subfolders: 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', etc.

Each subfolder has a some version of 'file.jar'
How can I search and copy the newest version?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point: consider using `FOR /R` for looping through all files recursively in a directory.  A [brief overview](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) is available at ss64.  Also see Rob van der Woude's page on [reading file properties](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_fileproperties.php) in a for loop.  Both sites are excellent scripting resources.

For example, the following command will list all files starting with 'a' (case insensitive) in directory `C:\A` and each file's last-modified date,

```
FOR /R C:\A %%G IN (a*) DO @ECHO %%G %%~tG
```

However, finding the file version itself is a bit more tricky.  See [How do I retrieve the version of a file from a batch file on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706892/how-do-i-retrieve-the-version-of-a-file-from-a-batch-file-on-windows-vista)