# How to use cmd to extract file version information from a directory?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

How can i extract the version number of a file present within a directory using command line in my batch script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the version of a file from a batch file on Windows Vista?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706892/how-do-i-retrieve-the-version-of-a-file-from-a-batch-file-on-windows-vista)

Comment: Sorry but I am looking from the support perspective so that the patch that we create for our software works on any windows machine. I do not want it to be dependent on any other external utility which would not server the purpose For ex: powershell doesnt exist in all the machines and customers/clients may not have it on their machines.

Comment: I have used sygcheck to fetch the information and then sfk to get the binary version of the file which comes out this way  Binary Version: 9.1.0.37019, i would like just "9.1.0.37019" and nothing before that in my temp file which means anything that comes before it is to be removed from within the file. How could i possibly do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used sigcheck utility to extract file version info.

I downloaded sigcheck.exe which is about 290KB and then fetched the file version info using this command:

SIGCHECK -a C:\Program Files(x86)\Software\bin\Software.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can try this batch file wrapped with powershell :

```
@echo off
echo.
set /p PathFile="Enter the absolute path to your application to retrieve its version > "
echo.
SET ScriptDirectory=%~dp0
SET ScriptPath=%ScriptDirectory%FileVersion.ps1 
echo (Get-Item '%PathFile%').VersionInfo.FileVersion > %ScriptPath%
cmd /k PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""%ScriptPath%""
```

Comment: Thanks Hackoo, I believe sigcheck has done the job for me. and i extract a certain information generated out of sigcheck. Now i need to do the following: 1. I have the detabbed output in a tmp file, i want to remove the first 17 characters from the tmp file and put the result in another temp2 file 2. Then i want to store the value in temp2 in a variable so that i can use the variable for IF conditions. Could you please advise?

Comment: Ok i have managed to do this by sfk replace and i have a value know which i put into a variable by using set /p string =< test.tmp. Now in the next step i want to compare %string% value for ex: if %string% EQU 9.1.0 GOTO Install but this doesnt seem to be working.... how do i use If statement here in cmd?