# Can I use Windows Scripting Host to take note of program versions?

Tags: vbscript, numbers, version, wsh, jscript

I'm learning about WSH, and wondering if it's possible to use a script to get program version numbers and write them to a text file.

I currently have to manually go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, and write out the version numbers, and I'm looking to automate this process.

Also, we CANNOT use Powershell, since our environment has those capabilities switched off.

Is this task possible through JScript or something similar, and how would I get started?

Comment: Yes. Check the subkeys of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

Comment: You can get file version of any application using WMIC by a batch script, so if you want to post it for you this code, just add the tag batch !

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830679/388389)