# How to detect a file by version, to uninstall any versions prior to a given iteration?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, uninstallation

I'm looking to leverage this command to detect the version and set a script to remove any version less than a certain number. The output typically includes the word Version and the number. How do I select only the second line or output only the numbers.

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe' get version
```

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830679/388389

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WQL does not have any type of rownum keyword or string functions. You could use a batch file to process the output for you.

Assuming your output is like:

```
version 1
version 2
version 3
```

Put the following in a batch script:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do call :Process %%a

:Process
echo %2
goto :eof
```

Pipe your output to it:

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe' get version | batch.bat
```

If your output is:

```
version1
version2
version3
```

use:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do call :Process %%a

:Process
set v=%1
echo %v:~7,8%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

I would place the WMIC command into a `For` loop and capture its output as a variable.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ExePath=C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC DataFile Where "Name='%ExePath:\=\\%'"^
 Get Version 2^>Nul') Do For /F %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "ExeVer=%%B"
Echo(%ExeVer%
Pause
```

*Just modify the fullpath target file on line `2` as necessary.*