# Windows: Command line to read version info of an executable file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, version, portable-executable

Does Windows have an executable that I can run in the command shell which returns the version number of an executable (.exe) file?

I see a lot of questions that show how to do it from different languages, and references to third party software to write it, but I can't find a simple shell command to do it. Additional points if I don't need to install anything.

It must be run as normal user. Not administrator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command line tool to dump Windows DLL version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\msiexec.exe" get Version /value
```

You can use `wmic` to do it. And you can wrap it into a batch file

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "file=%~1"
    if not defined file goto :eof
    if not exist "%file%" goto :eof

    set "vers="
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic datafile where name^="%file:\=\\%" get Version /value 
    ') do set "vers=%%a"

    echo(%file% = %vers% 

    endlocal
```

Save it as (example) `getVersion.cmd` and call as `getVersion.cmd "c:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe"`

**edited** to adapt to comments and not require administrator rights. In this case, an hybrid cmd/javascript file is used to query wmi. Same usage

```
@if (@this==@isBatch) @then
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "file=%~f1"
    if not exist "%file%" goto :eof

    cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" /file:"%file%"

    endlocal

    exit /b
@end
    var file = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('file').replace(/\\/g,'\\\\');
    var wmi = GetObject('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\cimv2')
    var files = new Enumerator(wmi.ExecQuery('Select Version from CIM_datafile where name=\''+file+'\'')) 

    while (!files.atEnd()){
        WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(files.item().Version);
        files.moveNext();
    };
    WScript.Quit(0)
```

Comment: Great, but unfortunately you must be in the Administrator group to run it :-( I need to run it as my continuous integration user.

Comment: How do you use %vers% afterwards? When I try `echo %vers%` the command prompt informs me `ECHO is off.`

Comment: @AlainD, the `setlocal / endlocal` prevents changes in the environment to propagate out of the batch file. If you need the `%vers%` value, change the ending `endlocal` line to `enlocal & set "vers=%vers%"`

Comment: @mc-nd  small typo:     enDlocal & set "vers=%vers%

Comment: @AndrewDennison, you are right, thank you. Unfortunately  I'm not allowed to edit the comment.

Answer (score 34):

If you are willing and able to use PowerShell, the following code will work. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

```
(Get-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe').VersionInfo |
    Format-List -Force
```

If you must run it in a cmd.exe shell, you could use:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe').VersionInfo |" ^
        "Format-List -Force"
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most clear answer, while directly applicable to PS without any other dependencies.

Comment: @lit but ProductVersion and FileVersion can be empty with PowerShell 7.2.5.

Comment: @user894319twitter, pwsh.exe has values; `FileVersion : 7.2.5.500, ProductVersion : 7.2.5 SHA: 0aad398b0e918ce7d73dca929ca6395639085b21`. No tool can control if the creator of the file pur information into the field. I am not understanding your point.

Answer (score 21):

```
set EXE='c:\firefox\firefox.exe'
powershell "(Get-Item -path %EXE%).VersionInfo.ProductVersion"
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.

Comment: "add an explanation of why it does so" Because it is designed to do so? These template questions are pointless.

Comment: No, because you have set the current active exe file powershell will interpret with the first line and then you used a powershell command on the currently active exe.

Comment: What? I'm actively using this snippet in several Jenkins jobs, but please tell me how it's not working, or whatever...

Comment: @bviktor but ProductVersion and FileVersion can be empty with PowerShell 7.2.5.

Comment: That's not a PowerShell issue, that's an issue with the executable. If they don't fill in that field, obviously you can't query it.

Comment: Finally an answer that works at all. Also very clean and simple.

Answer (score 12):

This will give you only the file version:

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe' get version
```

Result:

```
Version
6.1.7601.18917
```

Comment: Hi, code-only answers tend to be flagged for moderation. Could you add a line explaining what this does please?

Comment: This answer should be on top. Short, concise and on point, not to mention working, unlike the current accepted answer!

Comment: Is there a way to get the version without needing to pass in the path, i.e. use the directory that the command is run in?

Answer (score 3):

and one way with `makecab`:

```
; @echo off
;;goto :end_help
;;setlocal DsiableDelayedExpansion
;;;
;;;
;;; fileinf /l list of full file paths separated with ;
;;; fileinf /f text file with a list of files to be processed ( one on each line )
;;; fileinf /? prints the help
;;;
;;:end_help

; REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
; set NLM=^


; set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
; if "%~1" equ "/?" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; if "%~2" equ "" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
; if "%~1" equ "/l" (
;  set "_files=%~2"
;  echo !_files:;=%NL%!>"%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  set _process_file="%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  goto :get_info
; )

; if "%~1" equ "/f" if exist "%~2" (
;  set _process_file="%~2"
;  goto :get_info
; )

; echo incorect parameters & exit /b 1
; :get_info
; set "file_info="

; makecab /d InfFileName=%TEMP%\file.inf /d "DiskDirectory1=%TEMP%" /f "%~f0"  /f %_process_file% /v0>nul

; for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%f in ("%TEMP%\file.inf") do (
;  set "file_info=%%f"
;  echo !file_info:,=%nl%!
; )

; endlocal
;endlocal
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.inf 2>nul
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.path 2>nul
; exit /b 0

.set DoNotCopyFiles=on
.set DestinationDir=;
.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFooter=;
.set InfHeader=;
.Set ChecksumWidth=8
.Set InfDiskLineFormat=;
.Set Cabinet=off
.Set Compress=off
.Set GenerateInf=ON
.Set InfDiskHeader=;
.Set InfFileHeader=;
.set InfCabinetHeader=;
.Set InfFileLineFormat=",file:*file*,date:*date*,size:*size*,csum:*csum*,time:*time*,vern:*ver*,vers:*vers*,lang:*lang*"
```

example output (it has a string version which is a small addition to wmic method :) ):

```
c:> fileinfo.bat /l C:\install.exe
    file:install.exe
    date:11/07/07
    size:562688
    csum:380ef239
    time:07:03:18a
    vern:9.0.21022.8
    vers:9.0.21022.8 built by: RTM
    lang:1033
```

also you can take a look at [tooltipinfo.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat)

Answer (score 1):

filever c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
(the filever is preinstalled on every Windows OS).

Comment: I typed `where filever` and nothing was found.

Comment: Apparently, filever is no longer available on Windows 10. Although OP didn't specify the OS version, I'm adding this comment here for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

filever.exe is in SUPPORT.CAB from the Windows 2003 Support tools, and maybe other places.

A method using VBScript and Scripting.FileSystemObject from a CMD script

```
@Echo off
Set Version=
Echo WScript.Echo "Set Version=" ^& CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFileVersion("%SystemRoot%\notepad.exe") >%temp%\~FileVer.vbs
Cscript.exe //nologo %temp%\~FileVer.vbs>%temp%\~FileVer.cmd
Call %temp%\~FileVer.cmd
Echo Version=%Version%
```

A variant of the powershell method, if you are calling from a CMD script.
Using FileVersionRaw instead of FileVersion, because FileVersion can have extra text decoration, but have to ToString() to get the expected format.

```
@Echo off
Set Version=
Powershell -c "'Set Version=' + (Get-Command '%SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe').FileVersionInfo.FileVersionRaw.ToString()">%temp%\~FileVer.cmd
Call %temp%\~FileVer.cmd
Echo Version=%Version%
```

A Powershell from CMD method to compare versions, as that could be the reason for asking in the first place.
Have to use %ErrorLevel%==x because ErrorLevel==x is actually greater or equal.

```
@echo off
Powershell -c "exit 10 + ((Get-Command '%SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe').FileVersionInfo.FileVersionRaw).CompareTo([System.Version] '10.0.19041.1')"
If %ErrorLevel%==9  Echo File needs updating
If %ErrorLevel%==10 Echo File is expected version
If %ErrorLevel%==11 Echo File is newer than expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran this in unelevated PowerShell to get the version of Thunderbird:

```
(Get-Item -Path "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

It outputs the Product Version by filtering it out from the Version Info.
Tested it with chrome.exe and it also worked.