# Windows Batch File for getting file name and version on a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, version

Experts,

Requirement is to get all the Filename and FileVersion in the directory path

Example:

> Directory_Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Document Capture

When I run the batch it should ideally list out all the filenames and associated fileversion of the file (shouldnt consider any file without version or shouldnt consider any folder)

My Expected Output:

```
Filename   Fileversion

--------   -----------

vabc.dll   1.3

vabd.dll   1.3

vace.dll   1.4
```

I found this to work on our Windows 2008 R2

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\msiexec.exe" get Version /value
```

Source= [Windows: Command line to read version info of an executable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648155/windows-command-line-to-read-version-info-of-an-executable-file)

But i couldnt figure a way out to pass each of the filename into this command automatically and get me the output in a text file.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to specify the drive and path in the WHERE clause, and let WMIC discover the file names. You can also specify VERSION IS NOT NULL in the where clause.

The listed FileName will be the base file name only, without the extension. The extension is available in the Extension column (fancy that!).

```
wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path='\\Program Files (x86)\\Oracle\\Document Capture\\' and version is not null" get FileName, Extension, Version
```

Columns are always listed in alphabetical order (by name), regardless what order you requested. So you should get output like the following:

```
Extension  FileName  Version
dll        vabc      1.3
dll        vabd      1.3
dll        vace      1.3
```

Or you can request the Name column instead of FileName and Extension, but that will include the complete path.

```
Name                                                     Version
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Document Capture\vabc.dll  1.3
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Document Capture\vabd.dll  1.3
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Document Capture\vace.dll  1.4
```

The other option is to use a FOR loop to iterate all the files, and then pass the full path of each file in a separate WMIC call that is parsed by a FOR /F. There is an unfortunate "feature" (aka bug) with how FOR /F converts WMIC unicode output into ansi, such that all lines have an unwanted trailing carriage return (\r) that can lead to various problems. The unwanted trailing \r is eliminated by an extra FOR /F statement.

The VERSION IS NOT NULL clause is not needed because the pair of FOR /F statements will strip out lines that contain nothing but spaces.

```
@echo off
set "loc=C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Document Capture\"
pushd "%loc%"
for %%F in (*) do for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (
  'wmic datafile where "name='%loc:\=\\%%%F'" get version 2^>nul'
) do for /f "delims=" %%V in ("%%A") do echo %%F  %%V
popd
```

Output should then look like the following:

```
vabc.dll  1.3
vabd.dll  1.3
vace.dll  1.4
```