# How can I know that nk.bin has which version of .net Compact framework?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I want to know which .net compact framework version is embedded in to nk.bin file.
How can I know that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not read the CF version directly from NK.bin.

AFAIK you first have to dis-assemble NK.BIN and get all files within and then you can read the file version from mscore.dll.

To dis-assemble nk bin files you need some tools by xda developers and then you can do:

```
D:\_ROM\_nkbin_tools>viewbin.exe nkprm_en.bin
ViewBin... nkprm_en.bin
Image Start = 0x90300000, length = 0x01FA39F8
            Start address = 0x90301000
Checking record #30 for potential TOC (ROMOFFSET = 0xFE632D10)
Checking record #130 for potential TOC (ROMOFFSET = 0x00000000)
Found pTOC  = 0x9229f298
ROMOFFSET = 0x00000000
Done.
```

Then (with START and LENGTH values from above):

```
D:\_ROM\_nkbin_tools>cvrtbin.exe -r -a 0x90300000 -w 32 -l 0x01FA39F8 nkprm_en.bin
```

Then do mkdir dump and let the file been dumped to that dir:

```
D:\_ROM\_nkbin_tools>dumprom.exe -d dump -v -5 nkprm_en.nb0
```

[see also: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2078325]

Finally read the file version inside mscoree.dll (some of these may work: [Command line tool to dump Windows DLL version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version))