# How to determine version of imagemagick dll?

Tags: imagemagick

How do I determine the version number of the imagemagick .dll that is installed on windows?

The names of the files are:

```
Magick.NET-Q8-x64.dll
Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13118517/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You can find the version number in the 'Details' tab of the file properties window.

[image]

Or you could do what Mark Setchell suggested and use this: [Command line tool to dump Windows DLL version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version/13118517#13118517)