# Comprehensive list of programs on different operating systems

Tags: windows

How would I get a list of EVERY program into a text file for windows 95-windows 10. The uninstall programs in control panel doesn't have the version and publisher for the older operating systems, and wmic does not display every program. Even the uninstall registry, which I thought would be my savior, does not list every program. I can see discrepancies between that and the uninstall programs tab. Powershell and the like are off the table since it is relatively new.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  That is, why do you need this list?

Comment: I need to take inventory on computers and put them into excel spreadsheets. The spreadsheets need every program on the computer, the publisher, and the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some combination of the following:

1. Enumerate registry for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. And probably `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` on 64-bit os (might be duplicated).  These are the list of installed programs that appear in the Control Panel's "Program and Features" section.  Notice that some of the entries are straight-forward and have most of the data you want.  Others are a GUID - this corresponds to an MSI installation.
2. For all the entries obtained in #1 that reference a GUID, use the [MSI API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369426(v=vs.85).aspx) to find the installation information you seek.  Start with [MsiEnumProducts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370101(v=vs.85).aspx). From there you can get at version info of installed applications.
3. Brute force search for EXEs installed in `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`. For each EXE found, you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file) to get the version information.
4. You want a list of applications installed from the Windows Store? Ask me for a code sample if that's important too.

Answer (score 0):

The registry uninstall registration requirements in the 90's was just the display name and the command to start the uninstallation. Windows 2000 added support for more values and exposed them in the new UI but they were still optional. In recent years a couple of them became a requirement to pass the Windows Logo tests but they are still optional for non-certified applications so the uninstall key is not guaranteed to contain version/publisher information for every entry. Portable applications are not listed in the registry so if you need a inventory of everything then you need to inspect all exe files and ignore the registry.

Supporting everything back to Win95 RTM is going to be tough since you have nothing except batch files as a scripting option. VBScript is a optional component that normally gets installed with IE 4 and I don't even remember if it is possible to get Powershell on these systems.

I don't think it is possible to extract the version information with a simple batch file, you probably need the help of a 3rd-party tool. The issue with 3rd-party tools is that a lot of them depend on the [Microsoft CRT run-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#Runtime_libraries) .DLLs and Windows 95 RTM does not have them out of the box, not even msvcrt.dll.

If you can raise your requirement for Win95 to have Windows Scripting Host installed (redistributable or part of IE4) then you could write a VB/Jscript file that uses the FileSystemObject to both walk the entire directory tree on every drive and to [get version information](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/04/18/how-can-i-determine-the-version-number-of-a-file/) from .exe files.

If that is unacceptable then you need to try to find a tool that can extract version information. There is a Microsoft tool named filever.exe [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602866/3501) but I don't know if it works on Win95 and a NirSoft tool [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/exeinfo.html) but I'm not sure if it supports stdout redirection from the commandline (but it is open source so you could fix that if needed). Even if you find a suitable tool you would still need to walk the directory tree looking for .exe files and that is not going to be fun when you are limited to command.com and its DOS compatible batch handling.

My recommendation is to write a new application. I can't recommend writing it in a .NET language because you would be dealing with versions 1-4 and it is not installed on XP and older by default.

The way I see it, you have 3 options if you are writing it yourself: Visual Basic 6, Delphi (something old, v3 or older perhaps) or C/C++.

For C/C++ any version of Microsoft Visual C++ or MinGW/GCC will do but the older the better and you must not link to or use any C run-time library stuff (you might get away with static linking with MinGW but not recent versions of Visual Studio). If I was doing this I would use Visual Studio 6 or 2003 and build with [/Zl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1tbxcxh.aspx) & [/NODEFAULTLIB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a.aspx). There are [multiple](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15156/Tiny-C-Runtime-Library) [small standalone CRT libraries](http://www.malsmith.net/minicrt/) if you need them. If you use any recent version of Visual Studio you will manually have to hex-edit the file to [make it run](http://louis.steelbytes.com/vs2008_vs_win40.html) on anything older than XP.

The actual implementation needs to call [FindFirstFile**A**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and friends) on Windows 95/98/ME and FindFirstFile**W** on other systems to walk the directory tree and [`GetFileVersionInfoA/W`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx) (and friends) to get version info.

If you are feeling fancy you could perhaps filter out files in %WinDir% signed by Microsoft. Good luck...