# Reading the manifest of an EXE or DLL without loading it

Tags: c++, manifest

Is it possible in C++ to read the manifest of an EXE file or DLL whitout loading it?
I read that there are some API functions such as `FindResourceEx`, but they require `HMODULE` acquired by `LoadLibrary`.
(I do have the file handle of the exe or DLL I want to get the manifest from).

Comment: Read this link on how to extract it from the .Exe file:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420852/reading-an-applications-manifest-file

Comment: But they actually load the library. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get an `HMODULE` from `LoadLibraryEx(file, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE)`.